# How to edit Billing Address Label to Shipping Address in the thank you page and customer email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

In my WordPress site after customer place an order a thank you page will be shown

This is my thank you page, at the bottom under customer details I want to edit billing address label to Shipping address
[image]

This is my customer side email in this also at the bottom under customer details I want to change Billing address to Shipping Address [image]

I tried editing order/order-details-customer.php file and changed the following line from Billing to Shipping address but not working

```
<h3 class="woocommerce-column__title">
    <?php _e( 'Shipping address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you need to do that change from `email-addresses.php` file inside email folder.

Go to `email-addresses.php` and change this line ,

```
<h3><?php _e( 'Billing address', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked for me with the customer email, if you also know how to change the Billing Address to Shipping Address in the thank you page please let me know

Comment: Yes for that go to order/order-details-customer.php and change

Comment: I did that already but it didn't work, is there any other method or plugin which I can use

Answer (score 0):

Instead of renaming the titles from admin panel give billing and shipping address same. As you are specifying shipping address, shipping means something.